# How to run services of one pc from another pc

Tags: c#

I have a code that tries to access the services of another computer.

```
try
{
    var serviceName = "MyService";
    var ip = "10.10.11.16";
    var username = "SomeUser";
    var password = "APassword";
    var connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();
    connectoptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    connectoptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
    connectoptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
    connectoptions.Username = username;
    connectoptions.Password = password;
    var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\10.10.11.16\\root\\cimv2");
    scope.Options = connectoptions;

    var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Service where name = '" + serviceName + "'");
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    {
        var collection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject service in collection.OfType<ManagementObject>())
        {
            if (service["started"].Equals(true))
            {
                service.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
                BtnStartStop.Content = "Stop";
                LblService.Content = serviceName;
                LblServiceStatus.Content = "Stopped";
            }
            else
            {
                service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                BtnStartStop.Content = "Stop";
                LblService.Content = serviceName;
                LblServiceStatus.Content = "Running";
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Will this work on Server and client only? Won't this work on regular pc to another regular pc? Each time I run this when I get to the part of:

```
var collection = searcher.Get();
```

I get an error of

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Do you have an idea on to make this work? Thank you.

**STEPS DONE SO FAR**
Followed the instruction on

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-starting-with-vista

typed in the cmd with admin privilege

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

I even turned off the firewall just to be sure.

edited the registry of the pc I am connecting to this:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WBEM\CIMOM\AllowAnonymousCallback
>
> ```
>            Data type
>
>            REG\_DWORD
> ```

As for the antivirus, the pc I am connecting to does not have any anti virus.

I still get the same error.

Comment: Well the Error message is very clear: the User that starts the service has no permission to access the processes to the other pc. But that can have many reasons like: Firewall / ports are blocked, Antivirus blocking something, AD-Permissions missing and so on... But there is no way of telling by the information provided

Comment: @colosso Sorry for not placing that information in. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As @colosso pointed out, you are receiving that error message because you do not have permission on the remote host to connect to the WMI service.

You should follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-starting-with-vista) to ensure the remote host is configured to allow your connection.

Comment: @Ibanez1408, please check the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/securing-a-remote-wmi-connection#setting-dcom-security-to-allow-a-user-to-access-a-computer-remotely to ensure the user you are using has the appropriate permissions